# programmatically identifing the iphone device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to identify the device on which my application is installed. 
That means, when I install the app on the iphone, it should tell me the device information.
The information is like, the device is 2G, 3G or 3GS.

Currently I am getting only model, name, systemName, systemVersion of the device.

I want to know the device is 2G , 3G or 3GS.

please help me.

Answer (score 8):

In the past history of Mac programming, this was always considered the wrong question.

What you really need to know is a more specific piece of information. Ask a much more narrow question for each behavioral decision in your code. For example, you may need to know if the device has GPS or not. Another is that you shouldn't decide how to use the OpenGL stack based on what model device it is, but rather on the OpenGL capabilities/extensions information that is provided.

The information you're getting now is from UIDevice, which is an unfortunately poorly designed API. It provides you with exactly the wrong information in the worst possible format -- strings.

Erica Sadun has an extension to UIDevice that may be useful [here](http://github.com/ars/uidevice-extension/tree/master). It's just a wrapper for `sysctlbyname("hw.machine", ...)`. This property is different for each model.

But again, this is usually the wrong question.

Comment: Agreed. Unless you're working on an app that just inventories all the different iPhone in a corporations fleet and you need to be able to sort them, you probably don't need to know whether it's 3G or 3Gs, as much as whether it supports a feature you'd like to access.

Use the AvailibilityMacros to find out if your needed functionality is supported on the device.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I used in my app and it works great

```
NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
NSLog(@"DEVICE TYPE %@", deviceType);

struct utsname systemInfo;
uname(&systemInfo);

  - (NSString *) platformString{
NSString *platform =  [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
NSLog(@"type ...%@", platform);


if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 1G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 1G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 2G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 3G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 4G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2 (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
return platform;
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I made this, it even shows you the model number:

```
struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);

    NSString *modelName = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *machinename = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSString *modelnumber = @"Not listed";

    //Simulator
    if([modelName isEqualToString:@"i386"] || [modelName isEqualToString:@"x86_64"]) {
        modelName = @"iPhone Simulator";
        modelnumber = @"XXXXX";

    }

    //iPhone
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"]) {
        modelName = @"iPhone";
        modelnumber = @"A1203";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"]) {
        modelName = @"iPhone 3G";
        modelnumber = @"A1241/A1324";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"]) {
        modelName = @"iPhone 3GS";
        modelnumber = @"A1303/A1325";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"]) {
        modelName = @"iPhone 4 (GSM)";
        modelnumber = @"A1332";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,2"]) {
        modelName = @"iPhone 4 GSM Rev A";
        modelnumber = @"Not listed";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"]) {
        modelName = @"iPhone 4 (CDMA)";
        modelnumber = @"A1349";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"]) {
        modelName = @"iPhone 4S";
        modelnumber = @"A1387/A1431";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"]) {
        modelName = @"iPhone 5 (GSM)";
        modelnumber = @"A1428";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"]) {
        modelName = @"iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)";
        modelnumber = @"A1429/A1442";
    }

    //iPod touch
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"]) {
        modelName = @"iPod touch 1G";
        modelnumber = @"A1213";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"]) {
        modelName = @"iPod touch 2G";
        modelnumber = @"A1288";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"]) {
        modelName = @"iPod touch 3G";
        modelnumber = @"A1318";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"]) {
        modelName = @"iPod touch 4G";
        modelnumber = @"A1367";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"]) {
        modelName = @"iPod touch 5G";
        modelnumber = @"A1421";
    }

    //iPad
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"]) {
        modelName = @"iPad 1G";
        modelnumber = @"A1219/A1337";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"]) {
        modelName = @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
        modelnumber = @"A1395";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"]) {
        modelName = @"iPad 2 (GSM)";
        modelnumber = @"A1396";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"]) {
        modelName = @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
        modelnumber = @"A1397";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"]) {
        modelName = @"iPad 2 (WiFi + Rev A)";
        modelnumber = @"A1395";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"]) {
        modelName = @"iPad 3 (WiFi)";
        modelnumber = @"A1416";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"]) {
        modelName = @"iPad 3 (GSM+CDMA)";
        modelnumber = @"A1403";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"]) {
        modelName = @"iPad 3 (GSM)";
        modelnumber = @"A1430";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"]) {
        modelName = @"iPad 4 (WiFi)";
        modelnumber = @"A1458";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"]) {
        modelName = @"iPad 4 (GSM)";
        modelnumber = @"A1459";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"]) {
        modelName = @"iPad 4 (GSM+CDMA)";
        modelnumber = @"A1460";
    }

    //iPad mini
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"]) {
        modelName = @"iPad mini (WiFi)";
        modelnumber = @"A1432";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"]) {
        modelName = @"iPad mini (GSM)";
        modelnumber = @"A1454";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"]) {
        modelName = @"iPad mini (GSM+CDMA)";
        modelnumber = @"A1455";
    }

    //Apple TV, just for funn:)
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"AppleTV2,1"]) {
        modelName = @"Apple TV 2G";
        modelnumber = @"A1378";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"AppleTV3,1"]) {
        modelName = @"Apple TV 3G";
        modelnumber = @"A1427";
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"AppleTV3,2"]) {
        modelName = @"Apple TV 3G (Rev A)";
        modelnumber = @"A1469";
    }

    NSLog(@"Device model: %@/ %@ /%@",modelName,machinename,modelnumber);
```