# Detect CPU cores on iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I am writing some code with `dispatch_async` and get different results on an iphone 4s and ipad 1st gen.

I am wondering if it is due to the number of cores the CPU has. Is it possible to detect the number of cores or CPU type of an iOS device at runtime so I can `dispatch_async` on the 4s, but not on the ipad?

Comment: dont think it deserved a downvote for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the code to detect the number of cores on an iOS device:

```
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

unsigned int countCores()
{
    size_t len;
    unsigned int ncpu;

    len = sizeof(ncpu);
    sysctlbyname ("hw.ncpu",&ncpu,&len,NULL,0);

    return ncpu;
}
```

In addition to that, you can check against the `[[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]` to determine if the device is an iPhone or an iPad. Like this:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    NSLog(@"iPad");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"iPhone");
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241936/how-do-i-detect-a-dual-core-cpu-on-ios)

Comment: `#include <sys/sysctl.h>` is a private library, isn't?

Comment: I don't think so. It's just a standard C library.

Comment: For people looking for physical cores, use the key: hw.physicalcpu instead