# Meaning of NSProcessInfo physicalMemory value

Tags: ios, cocoa, memory

According to the [NSProcessInfo docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSProcessInfo/physicalMemory), `-physicalMemory` returns the "amount of physical memory in bytes.". However, on my 32 GB iPhone 5, it returns `1065000960`, which is only around 1 GB (1016 MB). What's up with that? Does it actually return the number of blocks or something? Could this be a bug in the API?

FWIW, I get the same value [using `sysctl()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8072278/79202).

Comment: You are confusing RAM (volatile memory) and disk (non-volatile storage). They're separate things. The value you're getting is the device's RAM size.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: iPhones don't have disks.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Holy crap, you are so right! id10t question.

Comment: He ment "RAM" and "ROM" i think and that's ok to call it Disk just to get it point :)

Comment: @DekelMaman: That's a strange thing to say in a community full of pedants.  He didn't mean ROM either.

Comment: @RobertHarvey iPhones may not have disks, but they have separate RAM and file system interfaces, like most computers. I have 32 GB of storage, but only 1 GB of RAM.

Comment: Obviously they don't *literally* have spinning disks, but the flash storage can be thought of as an SSD (Solid State Disk).

Comment: Hehehe stupid conversation :) anyway i think he got the idea

Comment: It is a stupid conversation until one of your relatives comes up to you with a 3 1/2 inch floppy and asks you "Where do I put this hard disk?"

Comment: Yes. So do I add my own answer to the effect that I'm confused, or will @AndrewMedico do it so I can accept?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Phones may not have hard disks, but they do have flash memory (non-volatile storage) which is treated exactly like a hard disk.

Comment: @David: Yes, I think we've already established that.  But thanks for pointing it out again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-physicalMemory` method is returning the amount of RAM (volatile storage) present in the device, which for the iPhone 5 is 1GB.

The "32GB" figure quotes in the device model is non-volatile flash storage (think SSD), which is separate from RAM.