# How to identify ipad 1 and ipad 2 individually at runtime

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, ipad-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk)
>   [iPad 2 detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337924/ipad-2-detection)

Please guide me on how to detect ipad and ipad 2 at runtime on real device.. I want to load different images to both handsets due to performance issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Easiest and shortest way is to check for a camera, as said in [iPad 2 detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337924/ipad-2-detection) :

```
BOOL isIPad2 = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad &&
            [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]);
```

Or even simpler:
    `BOOL isiPad2 = [[self platform] isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"];`
Remember that the string can be `iPad2,2` and `iPad2,3` as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSString *)machine {
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *machine = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    free(machine);
    return platform;
}
```

- iPad 1 : @"iPad1,1"
- iPad 2 : @"iPad2,1"

Comment: Thank Niko.. it works :), but somewhere I read for IPAD 2 sometime you can get iPad2,1 or iPad2,2 or iPad2,3 (depend on operator). Any idea what kind of different string i need to check for iPad and iPad 2

Comment: If that is so, you can check for iPad2,x string doing this : NSRange range = [theMachineString rangeOfString:@"iPad2" options:(NSAnchoredSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]]; if (range.length > 0) {NSLog(@"Im a an iPad2");}