# Detecting iPad 3 vs iPad 2 device?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPad 2 detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337924/ipad-2-detection)

So the new Xcode version was released with support for iOS 5.1 and the new retina iPad.

I was wondering how you can write code to tell which device it is, maybe something similar to `[[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone`, so that we can customize our code and designs based on the resolution available.

Also, what would be the best way to test how your app would look in an iPad 3 resolution if you don't own an iPad 3?

Thanks