# how do I check if the device is iPad 3?

Tags: xcode, ipad, device, platform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting iPad 3 vs iPad 2 device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613237/detecting-ipad-3-vs-ipad-2-device)
>   [Programmatically detect an iPad 3 (HD)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688930/programmatically-detect-an-ipad-3-hd)

I am making an iPad app and want to know if the app is running in an iPad 2 or 3 so accordingly I can perform some action.

What would be the best way to find this?

I am currently using

```
NSString *platform = [[UIDevice currentDevice] platformString];
```

But it returns "Unknown iPad" when I run on iPad 3.

Comment: are you running the latest version of the sdk?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613237/detecting-ipad-3-vs-ipad-2-device ...check the screen rather than the device.

Comment: Why do you even need to know the exact model? It is usually better to check for hardware _features_ instead, such as a high-resolution screen or a camera... That way, it'll still work with the iPad 4.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I just want to know if the iPad is a retina device or not. How can I do that?

Comment: `BOOL isRetina = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] >= 2.0;`

Comment: @omz - You should convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: You guys are absolutely right. I only need to know if it runs retina or not. The link was very helpful. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's generally best to check for the device features you're interested in rather than looking for a specific model of device. Apple recommends this, and for good reason: if you design for features of the new iPad, your customers won't be happy if Apple releases another device with those features and your app doesn't support them.

If you need to determine whether you're on an iPad, check `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad`. If you need to see if you have a Retina display, check `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale`. Combine the two and you can find out if you're on an iPad with Retina display.

If you need other features specific to the new iPad, look in the API for those features: AV Foundation can tell you about the capabilities of the built-in camera, for example. There's probably some way to check for LTE, too, but I'm not aware of it.