# How do specify ios app not to support iPad 1?

Tags: ios, xcode

The game, we are about to submit to apple, requires much memory and GPU power. It's almost unplayable on iPad 1, so we decided to release it for all iPads excluding first generation.
How do I set up the project to be shown in AppStore as not supporting iPad 1?

The solution, I came up with, is to set UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities: gyroscope in info.plist file.
But I still have some questions about it:

- Would Apple reject the app cause it doesn't really use gyroscope?
- Why do the game still installs and can be run on iPad 1 from xCode?
- Does anybody know the correct solution for this task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337924/ipad-2-detection

Comment: Thanx Nishant. But the question isn't how to detect a device type. The goal is to make the app impossible to be installed on iPad 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common pattern is to also require a camera, which the first iPad lacked.

Multiple applications have done this, and it doesn't appear to be a review criteria, though your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanx. I will keep requirement of gyroscope and will hope that Apple reviewers are OK with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can set your deployment target to iOS 6, which is supported only by the iPad 2 and later.

Comment: Unfortunately there are still some people running iOS 5 on their iPad 2. I don't want to loose them.