# List of iOS device hardware revision numbers

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm amazed that I'm having trouble finding this, but does anyone have a listing of which iOS devices correspond to which revision numbers, such as "iPhone 4,1", etc?

Comment: Why do you need the hardware revision number?

Comment: Duplicate question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403854/programmatically-identifing-the-iphone-device, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081904/how-to-detect-ios-device-programmatically

Comment: @BlackFrog For analytics purposes.  I know it's not the right way to check for capability.

Comment: As long as you know @orange80 haha.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please don't use this in fragile if statements to block features of your app.

http://www.everyi.com/by-identifier/ipod-iphone-ipad-specs-by-model-identifier.html

```
Apple Device                              | Model Identifier 
--------------------------------------------------------------
iPad Wi-Fi (Original)                     | iPad1,1
iPad Wi-Fi/3G/GPS (Original)              | iPad1,1
iPad 2 (Wi-Fi Only)                       | iPad2,1 
iPad 2 (Wi-Fi/GSM/GPS)                    | iPad2,2
iPad 2 (Wi-Fi/CDMA/GPS)                   | iPad2,3 
iPad 2 (Wi-Fi Only, iPad2,4)              | iPad2,4
iPad 3rd Gen (Wi-Fi Only)                 | iPad3,1 
iPad 3rd Gen (Wi-Fi/Cellular AT&T/GPS)    | iPad3,3
iPad 3rd Gen (Wi-Fi/Cellular Verizon/GPS) | iPad3,2 
iPad 4th Gen (Wi-Fi Only)                 | iPad3,4 
iPad 4th Gen (Wi-Fi/AT&T/GPS)             | Pending 
iPad 4th Gen (Wi-Fi/Verizon & Sprint/GPS) | Pending
iPad mini (Wi-Fi Only)                    | iPad2,5 
iPad mini (Wi-Fi/AT&T/GPS)                | iPad2,6
iPad mini (Wi-Fi/Verizon & Sprint/GPS)    | iPad2,7
iPhone (Original/EDGE)                    | iPhone1,1
iPhone 3G iPhone1,2 1 iPhone 3GS          | iPhone2,1
iPhone 3G (China/No Wi-Fi)                | iPhone1,2* 
iPhone 3GS (China/No Wi-Fi)               | iPhone2,1*
iPhone 4 (GSM)                            | iPhone3,1
iPhone 4 (CDMA/Verizon/Sprint)            | iPhone3,3 
iPhone 4S                                 | iPhone4,1
iPhone 5 (GSM/LTE 4, 17/North America)    | iPhone5,1 
iPhone 5 (CDMA/LTE, Sprint/Verizon/KDDI)  | iPhone5,2
iPhone 5 (GSM/LTE 1, 3, 5/International)  | iPhone5,1
iPhone 5S                                 | iPhone6,1
iPod (Original/Scroll Wheel)              | None
iPod 2nd Gen (Touch Wheel)                | None
iPod 3rd Gen (10/15/30)                   | None 
iPod 3rd Gen (10/20/40)                   | None
iPod 3rd Gen (15/20/40)                   | None
iPod 4th Gen (ClickWheel)                 | None 
iPod U2 Edition (4th Gen)                 | None 
iPod photo (30)                           | None
iPod photo (40/60)                        | None
iPod Color Display                        | None 
iPod U2 Edition (Color)                   | None
iPod 5th Gen (with Video)                 | None
iPod U2 Edition 5th Gen                   | None 
iPod 5th Gen - Enhanced                   | None 
iPod U2 Edition 5th Gen Enhanced          | None
iPod classic ("Original"/6th Gen)         | None 
iPod classic (Late 2008/7th Gen)          | None 
iPod mini                                 | None
iPod mini (2nd Gen)                       | None
iPod nano                                 | None 
iPod nano (2nd Gen)                       | None
iPod nano 2nd Gen (RED)                   | None 
iPod nano (3rd Gen/Fat)                   | None
iPod nano (4th Gen)                       | None
iPod nano (5th Gen/Camera)                | None 
iPod nano (6th Gen/1.54" Multitouch/Clip) | None
iPod nano (7th Gen/2.5" Multitouch)       | None
iPod shuffle (White)                      | None 
iPod shuffle 2nd Gen (Silver)             | None
iPod shuffle 2nd Gen (Colors/Early 2007)  | None 
iPod shuffle 2nd Gen (Late 2007)          | None
iPod shuffle 2nd Gen (Late 2008)          | None
iPod shuffle 3rd Gen                      | None
iPod shuffle 3rd Gen (Colors)             | None 
iPod shuffle 4th Gen (Wheel/VoiceOver)    | None
iPod shuffle 4th Gen (2012)               | None
iPod touch (Original)                     | iPod1,1
iPod touch (2nd Gen)                      | iPod2,1
iPod touch (3rd Gen/8 GB)                 | iPod3,1 
iPod touch (3rd Gen/32 & 64 GB)           | iPod3,1 
iPod touch (4th Gen/FaceTime)             | iPod4,1 
iPod touch (4th Gen, 2011)                | iPod4,1
iPod touch (4th Gen, 2012)                | iPod4,1
iPod touch (5th Gen)                      | iPod5,1
```

Comment: This is exactly what he is looking for. would you prefer I quote the site? Fine.

Comment: My bad. I just read the comment you made without going to the link.