# The iPhone device sim is GSM or CDMA

Tags: ios, iphone

I am having an app in which i wanted to show that my ios device is using a sim which is GSM or CDMA. How to implement this in my code. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403854/programmatically-identifing-the-iphone-device

Comment: another link is http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/better-code-determine-device-types-and-ios-versions/

Comment: I want to know about the sim in the device is GSM or CDMA.